# How do I set the status code of response when stubbing server using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to stub a server response so that when the server is down I can see a given error webpage. My challenge now is that the server is getting stubbed with the code below, but I would like to stub not just the response body but the status code as well.

```
const apiUrl = "https://webtmanial.dadaere.com/judadalerer"
          cy.server()
         cy.route(
             'POST',
             apiUrl,
             500

    ).as('dadaResponse');
```

The response is stubbed using the above, but status code still returns as 200 as shown below

```
Status:       200 (OK)
cypress_runner.js:171102 Duration:     673
cypress_runner.js:171102 Stubbed:      Yes
cypress_runner.js:171102 Request:      {headers: {…}, body: {…}}
cypress_runner.js:171102 Response:     {headers: {…}, body: 500}
```

The Cypress doc have examples for stubbing the response, but there's no clear example of stubbing the status code.

Please is there a way I can set the status code for the stubbed server, so that it returns 500. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the status in [options](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Options) object as below:

```
cy.route({
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiUrl,
    status: 500,
    response: '{"error":"Some error"}', // json object stringified!
});
```